# Understanding the Expression parameter in GetMetaObject()

Tags: c#, dynamic

Ok, I have the following code inside a struct (for good reason, so don't argue) to support dynamic properties, but the ACTUAL properties and methods exist in an external dynamic object (pointed to by the struct value):

```
    public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter)
    {
        IDynamicMetaObjectProvider dynObj = ManagedObject ?? Engine.CreateObject<V8NativeObject>(this);
        return new DynamicMetaObject(Expression.Parameter(((ParameterExpression)parameter).Type, ((ParameterExpression)parameter).Name),
            BindingRestrictions.Empty, dynObj);
    }
```

This doesn't work, and gives the following error: "An IDynamicMetaObjectProvider V8.Net.InternalHandle created an invalid DynamicMetaObject instance."

I'm trying to avoid having to extend 'DynamicMetaObject' to build a bridge to 'dynObj' if at all possible, since 'dynObj' is ALREADY dynamic, and ALREADY has its own 'GetMetaObject()' method.  I'm aware that the "parameter" expression represents the current target, but is there a way to pass it along into the 'GetMetaObject()' method of the external object ('dynObj') without creating ANOTHER object as a bridge?

FYI: There's is another similar question with the same error, but I am trying to limit the number of objects getting created as much as possible (i.e. trying to prevent having to pollute the GC with bridge objects).